# Ошибка "Fatal error: Class '...' not found"

Tags: denwer, php

Вот код файла

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN">
<html>
<head>
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
</head>

<body>
<h3>блабла</h3>
<?php
session_start();
ob_start("ob_gzhandler");
//ob_implicit_flush();
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
error_reporting (E_ALL ^ E_NOTICE);
ini_set('display_errors','On');
define('CA', true);
require_once "config/db.conf.php";
require_once "config/conf.php";

$db = new db;
$db->query("select * from peoples where url=18");
while($line=$db->get_row()){
    echo '<ul><li class="first"><a href="'.$line['name'].'">'.$line['name'].'</a></li></ul>';
}
?> 
</body>
</html>
```

Пишет такую вот ошибку при запуске через денвер

> `Warning: session_start() [function.session-start]: Cannot send session cookie - headers already sent by (output started at X:\home\test1.ru\www\imeninnik.php:10) in X:\home\test1.ru\www\imeninnik.php on line 11`
>
> `Warning: session_start() [function.session-start]: Cannot send session cache limiter - headers already sent (output started at X:\home\test1.ru\www\imeninnik.php:10) in X:\home\test1.ru\www\imeninnik.php on line 11`
>
> `Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at X:\home\test1.ru\www\imeninnik.php:10) in X:\home\test1.ru\www\config\conf.php on line 2`
>
> `Fatal error: Class 'db' not found in X:\home\test1.ru\www\imeninnik.php on line 24`

Что это значит? Кто-нибудь сталкивался с этим?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ошибка `session_start()` лечится легко - нужно просто вынести вызовы функций `session_start();` и `ob_start("ob_gzhandler");` в самое начало файла. Потому как только пойдет вывод html кода, заголовки будут автоматически посланы.

А вот почему класс не найден... я тоже его не вижу. Видимо, где-то в другом файле он объявлен - тогда с помощью include нужно подключить этот файл. Но скорее всего имя класса db (а строка `$db = new db;` выглядит очень странно - переменная и класс имеют одно имя) указано неверно. Поищите верное название там, где был взят этот код или шаблон для него.

Answer (score 0):

`session_start()` вызывается до вывода текста в браузер.